# How "create a file named from the $cfg['install_key'] variable in the root path;"

Tags: php

I want install a cms who call LODEL in my Xampp for test.
But I don't understand the step 3.

The

1. Copy lodelconfig-default.php to lodelconfig.php in the root path of your installation;
2. comment the exit(); statement at the top of your lodelconfig.php file;
3. create a file named from the $cfg['install_key'] variable in the root path;
4. create a database on a mariadb/mysql server somewhere, ie:
   CREATE DATABASE `lodel` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
   GRANT ALL on `lodel`.* TO `lodeluser`@`127.0.0.1` IDENTIFIED BY "password";
5. fill at least the DB parameters in your lodelconfig.php file;
6. go to the lodel/scripts directory;
7. install the dependencies via composer (cd lodel/scripts && composer install);
8. go to http(s)://yoursite/yourlodelpath/lodeladmin/install.php, follow the final instructions.

Answer (score 0):

echo $cfg['install_key'] and create file by name value $cfg['install_key']

Comment: If value of $cfg['install_key'] = 123456.  I creat a file who name is 12345.    without extension.